# What am I? - An enigmatic riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> Most know what I am like,
>
> and yet some never will.
>
> Many objects possess me,
>
> but those you think do, do not.
>
> I have many siblings,
>
> and if you know me, you'll know 5 of them.
>
> Maybe you know ***of*** the other ones,
>
> but even then, you will never see them.
>
> My name does not contain the letter D,
>
> But I share my name with something that does.
>
> And I have no physical form,
>
> and yet you see me every day.
>
> What am I?

*Answer every line of the riddle in your answer for it to be counted correct*

Comment: Except for the letter D, I was going to say radiant energy.  Seemed so close. https://www.theclaycenter.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Energy-Curriculum-Forms.pdf

Comment: Maybe you could put the [enigmatic-puzzle] tag and remove the riddle tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You are Blue

---

Most know what I am like,

> Most people can see the color blue

and yet some never will.

> But some are blind and cannot

Many objects possess me,

> Lots of blue things out in nature, like the sky and ocean

but those you think do, do not.

> But in reality, what we see as blue is actually only reflecting blue light

I have many siblings,

> Lots of other colors and forms of light

and if you know me, you'll know 5 of them.

> Six other main colors in the visible spectrum

Maybe you know of the other ones,

> Kids learn about forms of light outside of the visible spectrum in school

but even then, you will never see them.

> Radio waves or ultraviolet light are not something you see with the naked eye

My name does not contain the letter D,

> Blue doesn't!

But I share my name with something that does.

> The song [Blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_(Da_Ba_Dee)) by Eiffel 65 contains plenty of "Dee"s.

And I have no physical form,

> Light isn't solid

and yet you see me every day.

> You literally see with light

Comment: You are *so* close to being right, yet not not quite enough. I'll give it to you if no one else gets it, though (you're that close!)

Comment: Could it be simply “light”? The reasons above are still valid. The siblings could be other forms of energy or spectrums of electromagnetic radiation. I figure this is close enough to Cellion’s answer, I don’t want to steal the win if this is it.

Comment: @will No. Cellion was right on every account except for his base answer and when he said (Rot13) gung "Dhvgr n srj crbcyr unir terra va gurve fheanzr" The actual answer is a bit more enigmatic than that.

Comment: I think my new guess essentially fits, but like the one that used someone's name, I don't feel like it's exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: @Cellion Alright, it doesn't seem like anyone else is going to answer correctly, so I think you should get the points for it now.